# Kubernetes client c# The SSL connection could not be established

Tags: c#, kubernetes

I am trying to connect with kubernetes cluster as follows and get the list of nodes, pods and services from the given aks cluster..

```
        var clientId = ".........";
        var clientSecret = ".........";
        var tenantId = "xxxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com";
        var subscriptionId = "...........";
        var clusterName = "aks-k8s";
        var resourceGroupName = "test";

        var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId,
                            clientSecret,
                            tenantId,
                            AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

        var azure = Azure.Configure()
                         .Authenticate(credentials)
                         .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

        IKubernetesCluster kubernetesCluster = azure.KubernetesClusters
            .GetByResourceGroup(resourceGroupName, clusterName);

        if (kubernetesCluster != null)
        {
            var buffer = kubernetesCluster.UserKubeConfigContent;
            var configStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);

            var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildConfigFromConfigFile(configStream, null, null);
            IKubernetes client = new Kubernetes(config);

            var nodes = await client.ListNodeAsync();

            foreach (var node in nodes.Items)
            {
                //update my database with this list.....
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(clusterName + " cluster does not exits");
        }
```

As there are no much support in the internet i couldn't able to figure out the issue. I can able to run this locally but when i tried to put this is azure function or azure web app i am getting the following errors

```
        The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

        at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface secModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SCHANNEL_CRED scc)   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SCHANNEL_CRED secureCredential)   at System.Net.Security.SslStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(X509Certificate certificate, SslProtocols protocols, EncryptionPolicy policy, Boolean isServer)   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32 readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.PartialFrameCallback(AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ThrowIfExceptional()   at System.Net.Security.SslState.InternalEndProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)   at System.Net.Security.SslState.EndProcessAuthentication(IAsyncResult result)   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(IAsyncResult asyncResult)   at System.Net.Security.SslStream.<>c.<AuthenticateAsClientAsync>b__47_1(IAsyncResult iar)   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1.FromAsyncCoreLogic(IAsyncResult iar, Func`2 endFunction, Action`1 endAction, Task`1 promise, Boolean requiresSynchronization)--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

What is it am i missing here.. help would be appreciated.

Comment: When an exception message says "see inner exception." - that's probably a good place to start looking. What was the inner exception?

Comment: Hi moreON... thank you for replying... but the credentials are correct.. its in the production environment it couldn't make the connection. As I have very little experience on this, can you suggest me changes what I can make in the above code. How i can suppress SSLPolicyError to none

Comment: hi... sorry for replying late.. any suggestion please

Comment: I have tried by setting "config.SkipTlsVerify = true;" to skip the ssl verification. But still after deploying to App Services.. still getting the same error